# Associate DNS name with web server on non-standard port

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, routing

I have a router that I am trying to run an SSL VPN over. When I go to set up the login page it is set to run over `port 4430` by default. This is good because we already have another service at that address running over `port 80 and 443`. So when I navigate to `https[:]//[Public IP]:4430` I get the login page but it is not a secure connection and I will not run this VPN if I cannot make it secure.

So I would like to give it a DNS name like VPN.Company.com so that I can go and get a cert for it but I am not sure how to associate the DNS with a non-standard port. I know A records can only be associated with an address so how do I set it up where the DNS name for `VPN.Company.com` resolves to `https[:]//[Public IP]:4430`?

**NOTE:** Currently DNS is not configured on the device, is this something that I would need to set up on the device?

Answer (score 2):

The SSL certificate is not related to the port. It is related to the name.

Acquire a certificate for the name you want to use for the VPN site. The port doesn't matter.

As for the DNS, you can't associate a port number with a standard DNS A record. You can associate a port with a DNS SRV record, but your VPN client would need to support SRV record lookups. If you're going to be accessing the VPN through a webpage URL then you're going to have to specify the port number in the URL.

Comment: Can you explain the SRV record a little more?

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this by creating a web page on port 443 that redirects the client to the new page with the port number (e.g. `https://[Public IP]:4430`). As @joeqwerty says there is no place for port numbers in a standard DNS record.

DNS runs as a service on your name servers, not on the target router.